# svnadmin load for a subdirectory

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server, svnadmin

I am trying to execute this line:

```
svnadmin load --parent-dir new/subdir/for/project /usr/local/svn/restored < repos-backup
```

I am trying to figure out how to load into a subdirectory

I got this example from http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re36.html and multiple other websites.

My command is:

```
svnadmin load D:/svn/Runners D:/svn/Runners/march/Mondays /I_do_not_know_what "/usr/local/svn/restored is" < D:/Users/administrator/Documents/dump
```

"D:/svn/Runners" is the parent directory or "/Runners" is the parent directory

"D:/svn/Runners/march/Mondays" is the subdirectory or "/march/Mondays/ is the subdirectory I am not sure

I do not know what: "/usr/local/svn/restored" should be

"D:/Users/administrator/Documents/dump" is the directory for the dump (that worked)

If not the `svnadmin load --parent-dir` ... command what svnadmin command would work for loading a subdirectory of a repository?

Any Ideas?

Comment: I found the right way: ............. D:\svn>svnadmin load D:/svn/Runners/ --parent-dir march/Mondays < C:/Users/administrator/Documents/dump ................... the /usr/local/svn/restored/ is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to the most outdated version of SVNBook, 1.0. The current version is [SVNBook 1.8](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/). The command-line reference you were looking for is [SVNBook | `svnadmin load`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.load.html).

Comment: Thanks for an updated version of what I am looking for.